# QemuSensors error in the LogCat

Tags: android

When I'm trying to implement SensorEventListener in my app, I got the following error message repeatedly in the LogCat:

```
12-25 17:33:57.210: ERROR/QemuSensors(58): data__poll: len=-1, errno=9: Bad file number
```

And this is how I declare the listener inside the activity class:

```
private final SensorEventListener mSensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) {
        // do something
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // do something
    }
};
```

The strange thing is, the app and the sensor seems to works just fine. Anyone knows how why is this happened and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Probably due to the fact that there's no sensors in the emulator.

Comment: I am also getting the same error in the logcat and the application is working fine. Couldn't find a valid reason till now.